# How to get only top 5 and bottom 5 lists from Nested list?

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-2.7, nested-lists

So right I'm working with a file with a bunch of lists within a list. I'm trying to arrange them by top 5 states and bottom 5 states for total number of participants.

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter #not really using this right now
crimefile = open('APExam.txt', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(crimefile)
allRows = [row for row in reader]
L = sorted(allRows,key=lambda x: x[1])
for item in L:
    print item[0],','.join(map(str,item[1:]))
```

Which prints something like this:

```
State  Total #,% passed,%female
Wyoming 0,0,0
New Hampshire 101,76,12
Utah 103,54,4
Mass 1067,67,18
Montana 11,55,0
Iowa 118,80,9
Alabama 126,79,17
Georgia 1261,51,18
Florida 1521,44,20
Illinois 1559,69,13
New Jersey 1582,74,15
Maine 161,67,16
```

This prints the file in a way that is nearly what I'm looking for but the total number of participants isn't sorted by the largest to lowest; it is sorted by looking at the first element. How do I change it to look more like:

```
New Jersey 1582,74,15
Illinois 1559,69,13
Florida 1521,44,20
Georgia 1261,51,18
Etc...
```

First time asking a question here, any help is appreciated! :) Also, I'm trying not to use the .sort() or find() function or the "in" operator-- such as "if 6 in [5, 4, 7 6] ..."

Edit*: By changing L

```
L = sorted(allRows,key=lambda x: int(x[1]),reverse=True)
```

I've gotten to the point where I have the list going in descending order:

```
State  Total #,% passed,%female
California 4964,76,22
Texas 3979,62,23
New York 1858,69,20
Virginia 1655,60,19
Maryland 1629,66,20
New Jersey 1582,74,15
Illinois 1559,69,13
Florida 1521,44,20
```

Now I can't quite seem to figure out how to only take the top 5 and bottom 5 based on these totals...

Answer (score 7):

For top five-

```
top_five = L[:5]
```

For bottom five-

```
bottom_five = L[-5:]
```

for detail https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/slice

Answer (score 1):

Seems you handled the sorting to your liking, so to get the top 5 and bottom 5 elements you can use the [list slicing](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists):

```
>>> L = range(15)
>>> L
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]

>>> L[:5]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> L[-5:]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are on the right track.

What you can do now is slice the resulting list:

```
>>> xs = sorted(range(10), reverse=True)  # A sorted list in descending order
>>> xs
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>>> xs[:5]  # Top 5
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5]
>>> xs[-5:] # Bottom 5
[4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>>>
```

You should be able to use the same kind of slicing in your problem.

See this useful guide [An Information Introduction to Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html?highlight=slice) (*with slice highlighted*)